# Telerik radwindow position

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I´m having a problem with telerik RadWindow.
In my application the following steps will happen:

1. User clicks on a button, the RadWindow will be visible (in the center of the window). The user will then pick a file to upload.
2. When the user press the upload button the RadWindow is still visible but now a DataTable with Data will also be visible in there. The telerik RadWindow is set to AutoSieze="true" so it can be extended when the DataTable being filled with data. But because of the new size the RadWindow is not in the middle anymore because of the bigger size.

I have tried to use the left and top properties to adjust the position but without any success. Is it possible to change the position of the radWindow either from Client or Server code? I also have tried moveTo(position) (JavaScript) but it´s not working.

Does anyone has similar problems?

Answer (score 1):

The RadWindow client-side object has a `center()` method, which you can call like this:

```
var oWnd = $find("<%= DialogWindow.ClientID %>");
oWnd.center();
```

Have a look at [the online documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-programming-radwindow-methods.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have already tried that without any success. It´s look like the RadWindow calculate the center of the screen from the upperLeft corner of the RadWindow. When I add the DataTable the upperLeft corner is in the same position but the size of the window has changed because of the DataTable size. Which will result that the Window will not be in the middle of the screen anymore.

Comment: @Tobias: I'd suggest you contact telerik support. They are usually very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to "force" the `center()` to apply by calling `show()`.

```
var oWnd = $find("<%= DialogWindow.ClientID %>");
oWnd.Center();
oWnd.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your **AutoSizeBehaviors** are left to **Default**. Thus it will keep centered after autosizing, setting them to other values may have the effect that the top left corner stays in place.

Also, try adding a timeout around center():

```
setTimeout(function(){
oWnd.center();
}, 0);
```